# как удалить из списка все единицы с#

Tags: c#, list

У меня есть лист например `[0, 1, 1, 1, 1]`.

Я хочу удалить отсюда все единицы, как это можно сделать?

```cs
List<int> fishes = new List<int>(5);
    
fishes.Add(0);
fishes.Add(1);
fishes.Add(1);
fishes.Add(1);
fishes.Add(1);

for (int i = 0; i < fishes.Count; i++)
{
    if (fishes[i] == 1)
    {
        fishes.Remove(1);
    }
}
```

Такой цикл не подойдет ибо в какой-то момент `i` станет больше чем `fishes.Count` и при этом ещё не все единицы удалятся

Можно создать новый лист и в него записывать все элементы, не равные единице, но не хочется создавать новый лист. Думаю какое условие можно придумать, чтобы реализовать мою задачу с помощью цикла

Comment: добавьте внутрь if `i--`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно оставить в списке только те элементы, которые не равны 1 используя LINQ:

```
fishes = fishes.Where(x => x != 1).ToList();
```

либо указать условие для удаления всех элементов:

```
fishes.RemoveAll(x => x == 1);
```

Если надо именно в цикле, то при удалении элемента, надо понизить `i`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < fishes.Count; i++)
{
    if (fishes[i] == 1)
    {
        fishes.RemoveAt(i);
        i--;
    }
}
```

Comment: к сожалению linq ещё не проходил

Comment: дополнил ответ без LINQ

Comment: c i-- действительно работает, не знаю как до этого можно было додуматься, но спасибо

Comment: Можно еще лёгкий изврат `int i; while ((i = fishes.IndexOf(1)) >= 0) fishes.RemoveAt(i);`.

Answer (score 3):

В ответе сверху три хороших варианта, а я приведу ещё два.

Идея №1.

При удалении элемента сдвигаются все индексы, начиная с индекса следующего за удалённым элемента и до конца. Поэтому чтобы с индексами не было проблем, перебираем массив с конца:

```cs
for (int i = fishes.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (fishes[i] == 1)
        fishes.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

Идея №2.

Каждое удаление элемента из середины — затратная операция, потому что нужно нужно сдвигать все элементы, возможно, по нескольку раз, в результате у кода квадратичная сложность. Поэтому сделаем такой трюк: пройдёмся по списку с начала в конец, и будем «уплотнять» его: перезаписывать элементы на освобождающиеся места, как на картинке

[image: визуализация]

Если идти слева направо, мы не будем при этом затирать нужные нам элементы.

За индекс сверху у нас будет отвечать переменная `i`, а за индекс снизу — `j`. В конце нужно будет «отрезать» ненужный хвост. Получается вот что:

```cs
int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < fishes.Count; i++)
{
    if (fishes[i] != 1)
    {
        if (i != j) // копировать в себя нет смысла
            fishes[j] = fishes[i];
        j++; // продвигаем целевой индекс только если не единица
    }
}
fishes.RemoveRange(j, fishes.Count - j);
```

Код здесь длиннее, но эффективнее на больших списках.

---

Проверка `i != j`, возможно, не очень хорошо влияет на предсказатель переходов процессора, поэтому не исключено, что без неё будет быстрее. Не тестировал.

Comment: спасибо, fishes.RemoveAll(x => x == 1); данный способ не будет самым,быстрым, менее занимающим место, решением моей проблемы по вашему мнению?

Comment: @Rotmayer: да, этот способ, думаю, самый лучший.